# SQL Server 2005 : putting a gap in 'Group By' results

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

I have a set of reports that are run that group by a set of results, when it is run now it looks like:

```
Column_1
1
2
3
```

Code:

```
Select Column_1, Other_Info  
From Some_Table  
Group By Column_1
```

But I want the result set to look like:

```
Column_1
1  

2

3
```

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes it is possible with a dirty hack. But I would **strongly** suggest that this is much better handled outside of SQL. SQL is for data, the application layer is for formatting. (It may be beneficial to ask a new question depending on where you are handling your results).

In order to do it you need to replicate the result set but with empty data (which means you need to make sure all your columns are varchar).

You then need to have a way of ordering the result set to ensure the blank rows are alternate (Sort1 and Sort2 in the below)

```
SELECT  Column1, OtherInfo
FROM    (   SELECT  Column_1 = CAST(Column_1 AS NVARCHAR), 
                    OtherInfo = CAST(Other_Info AS NVARCHAR), 
                    Sort1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Column_1), 
                    Sort2 = 1
            FROM    Some_Table  
            GROUP BY Column_1, OtherInfo
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  Column_1 = N'',
                    OtherInfo = N'',
                    Sort1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Column_1),
                    Sort2 = 2
            FROM    Some_Table  
            GROUP BY Column_1, OtherInfo
        ) d
ORDER BY Sort1, Sort2;
```

If your query is particularly costly you may want to consider using a temp table, rather than selecting twice and not using any data the second time.

Comment: Thank you that nearly works but the OtherInfo column is not being accepted as it is not in an aggregate function.

Comment: You will need to include it in the group by or include it as an aggregate column, without seeing your data or knowing your requirements I am not sure which.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`Select
Column_1
,Other_Info,
CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
From
Some_Table
Group By
Column_1`

Comment: Unfortunately it meant I had to group any column that was not affected by a function as well and still show as example 1.